# AJAX with loading progress

Tags: php, ajax

Basicallly,I want to receive the GPS location from an Android Phone. Firstly I send an AJAX request to a php file. This file will send a request to the phone to track its location. After the phone doing the GPS tracking, it send the data back to another PHP file to update the database. What I ask is that how to do a loading progress using AJAX or anything from the time that I send the request from server to the phone to the time that I receive the data from the phone. How to know that the phone has done the GPS stuff and notify to client. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Every GET call has a callback in which the request is finished. A loading screen doesn't really exist in Javascript/AJAX. You have to make it yourself. This isn't at all hard though: Get a loading gif to show up when starting the call. And hide it when the request is completed!

Comment: I could do something like this, on the php file that update the database, I could also add in a column to show that this file has received enough data or not and update this column maybe to true. On Ajax side, I send a request to another php file to check the database column that I add in above whether this column is true or not. However, I have to continously send the request through AJAX to this file to check the database continously ultil I receive the response OK. Do I actually have to do that or is there anyway to overcome this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we assume that you have a div with an id of #loading first, and after create two js functions

```
function loading_show(){
$('#loading').html('<img src="images/loaders/loader2.gif" style="vertical-align:middle;" /> Please Wait!').fadeIn('fast');
}

function loading_hide(){
$('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
}
```

Now using jQuery, if someone clicks on the button to retrieve the data from the server

```
    $('.selector').on("click", function() {
         loading_show();
         $.ajax
             ({
              type: "POST",
              ......
              data: data,
              success: function(msg)
              {
                  loading_hide();
                  //display results
                  //notify client about process    
              }
             });
         });
```

Comment: The problem is I dont know when will it success because I can not send the request to the php file that the phone send, I will not receive anything at all. I think I can create a column in the database and let the php file that receive from the phone update it. After that I will send AJAX request to another php file that check this column and receive the response. However I have to do this continously until the column return true. So i dont know how to achieve this

Comment: Maybe you could use triggers (db)

Comment: I have done some research and they say that trigger in database can not pass to php so I think can not use.